# redirecting the user to the same page after login

Tags: php

I have a header bar including a login form in every page of my website:

```
<header>
 <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Benutzername" type="text">
        <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Passwort" type="password">
      <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>  
</header>
```

When clicking submit a php script in a separate `login.php` is executed. `login.php` is also an extra page where the user can try again after failing to login.

`login.php` looks like this:

```
    $ousername = '';
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
    //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    }
    else
    {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    //We get the password of the user
    $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
    $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
    //We compare the submited password and the real one, and we check if the user exists
    if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
    {
        //If the password is right
       header('Location: index.php');
```

up here is where the problem starts. As you can see, the user is redirected to `index.php` when the form is sent and the login succeeds. What I would like to do is redirect the user to whatever page they are currently on when submitting the form (e.g. when the user is currently on a page that shows my website guidelines and logs in, I want him to be redirected to the very same guidelines-page when the login succeeds.)

I tried something like this:

```
if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
    {
   if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URl'] == login.php)){
       header('Location: index.php');
  } else {
       header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URl']);
}
```

This is the last part of login.php:

```
        //We save the user name in the session username and the user Id in the session userid
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];

        lots html following...
```

I hope this is clear. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that, you have no `$dn['password']` when you run the query? You are not selecting a `password` field, you are selecting `Passwort1_3`

Comment: I know, I just quickly changed that for this post :-P. Thanks though! Everything else works as it should

Comment: Ok, but please, do not do this in the futere, always show the actual code (except username / password). If you do it, we will think, the error is there.

Comment: Sidenote: never ever store your passwords as plaintext in the database. Please refer to [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) on how to encrypt and store passwords in a database

Comment: Its also recommended and good practise to add `exit;` after each `header('Location: xxxx');`

Comment: @DarkBee: password encryption is the next step on my schedule! - as to the `exit` part, that is to prevent extra loading time?

Comment: Its to be sure no extra code is executed after u called the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HTTP_REFERER instead of REQUEST_URl :

```
if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0) {
 if(($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] === "login.php")){
       header('Location: index.php');
  } else {
       header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }
}
```

Comment: `login.php` is string so wrap it in `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

to return to the very last page before the login process!

Answer (score 1):

You can access browser history using javaScript. Just include the script in the index page and send the users to the desired page.

Use `window.history.go` method
`window.history` reference
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history

Or without jS

http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070228/steal-browser-history-without-javascript/