# Two elements, keep one centered and second to it's left/right

Tags: alignment, center, element

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIA8b.png)

[Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1htcI.png)

I'm sure there's an answer somewhere, but I'm unable to find it. I've seen people use flex and it looked promising, but it just seems to break things up.

Original code:

```css
.checkImg {
 margin-left: 10px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

form {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838228/redirecting-the-user-to-the-same-page-after-login -->
  Nickname:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nickname"><img class="checkImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg"></img>
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="email"><img class="checkImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg"></img>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <form>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to set up the flex from here: [How to use flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891839/keep-one-element-centered-between-two-elements-of-different-widths-in-flexbox)

How it went:

```css
.checkImg {
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

form {
   text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-start
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838228/redirecting-the-user-to-the-same-page-after-login -->
  Nickname:<br>
  <div><input class="flex" type="text" name="nickname"><img class="checkImg flex" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg"></img></div>
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="email"><img class="checkImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg"></img>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried `flex-grow: 0` (sets input on the left side, image on the right start, removing the stretching), `align-items: flex-start` and none of these seemed to work. It feels like I'm really close, but since this is my first encounter with flex, I can't just seem to find the right solution.

Comment: I am not sure why you want flex here...i would keep it simple, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/p7810pnr/

Comment: Well, I thought there might be a better option how to do it. Thanks, I'll probably use that, I'll just wrap two of the pushed input fields into a class and set the margin-left +30px so it's actually centered on the page. It sounds simple and like a good solution. As I'm starting with programming, I'm just trying my best to avoid bad habits and code.

Comment: Yes, i will make and propose some better solution soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions, with flexbox. (Note: you can achieve same on many different ways). You can also use ::after pseudo-element, but in this example i kept your image. Trick is to set image position to absolute, and then it will not affect alignment.

```
    <form>

            <div >Nickname:<br>

    <input type="text" name="nickname" ><img class="checkImg flex" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg">
    </div>
<div>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
</div>

        <div>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email"><img class="checkImg flex" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg">
    </div>


        <div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <form>
```

CSS:

```
    form {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
flex-direction: column;
}
div {
margin:10px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;

}
.checkImg {
  position:absolute;
 right:-30px;
}
```

DEMO:

```css
form {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
flex-direction: column;
}
div {
margin:10px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
  
}
.checkImg {
  position:absolute;
 right:-30px;
}
```

```html
<form>
 
   <div >Nickname:<br>
 
    <input type="text" name="nickname" ><img class="checkImg flex" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg">
    </div>
<div>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password">
</div>

  <div>
     Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="email"><img class="checkImg flex" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1SRSjmKURx3aIkIUvNZg2iyyzhTctX1nPlfn8Yo49JdeffVG8Pg">
    </div>
 
  
  <div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
 <form>
```